# How to save the XML files in Computer?

Tags: c#, xml

In my project my app receives an XML from another program. I want to save this XML file in the folder in my PC. But if there is another XML file that will come, the XML will be added in the folder not overwrite the existing XML. How can I achieve it?

I am using this code right now but I don't know why I got an access denied error.

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\XML", abc);
```

Comment: Uhm, you (the current user) apparently doesn't have access to write the file "C:\XML". (Note that the error and the task are *not related*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error that you receive is because of Windows UAC which denies users without Administrator privileges to write on the C:\ disk. Create a folder in which you have access, for example "c:\temp\" and write your files in there.

Also, you specify a file and not folder.

And if you don't want to overwrite the file, just make sure to generate a unique filename (a guid perhaps).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how can I make my name unique? how can I concatenate the ID to my xml name?

Comment: string.Format("{0}-your-xml-name-here.xml", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()); This will do the trick of concatenating